# Trying to concatenate strings

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Here is my code:

```
resultText.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", symbol.data, ", ", symbol.typeName];
```

Running on the device (iPhone) in the debugger, it dies!  I am assuming this is the line that is doing it, but since the Debugger is so primitive, I'm just guessing, since this is the only line I changed from a working app.

What's wrong with it?  Where can I find a definitive book or something that would tell me how to do this in the future (like an O'Reilly book?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your middle string, the `", "` is a regular C string, not a Obj-C string. You need to prefix it with a `@`:

```
resultText.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", symbol.data, @", ", symbol.typeName];
```

(That said, I don't know why the comma bit needs to be separate like that. You could put it right in the format string.)

Comment: Thanks quixoto... I'm REAL new at this, having used Monotouch for the last several months (which I find much easier).